# How do I know when a point is a max or a min (multivariable optimisation problem)?

Tags: multivariable-calculus, optimization, lagrange-multiplier, karush-kuhn-tucker

I am stuck in understanding how I can deduce if the solution I found is a max or a min. The exercise reads:

$$\max \quad f(x, y) = 2x - y \qquad \text{subject to} \qquad \begin{cases} x^2+y = 2 \\ x+y \geq 0 \\ x \geq 0 \end{cases}$$

I wrote the problem in standard form, that is:

$$\max \quad f(x, y) = 2x - y \qquad \text{subject to} \qquad \begin{cases} x^2+y = 2 \\ -x-y \leq 0 \\ x \geq 0 \end{cases}$$

I derived the Lagrangian:

$$L(x, y, \lambda, \mu) = 2x - y - \lambda(x^2+y-2) - \mu(-x-y)$$

And I wrote down the optimal conditions:

$$\begin{cases}2 - 2\lambda x + \mu \leq 0 \\ 
x(2 - 2\lambda x + \mu) = 0 \\
-1-\lambda + \mu = 0 \\
x^2+y = 2 \\
x+y\geq 0 \\
\mu(x+y) = 0 \\
x, \mu \geq 0 
\end{cases}
$$

From here I distinguished two cases over $\mu$. If $\mu = 0$ I obtain $\lambda = -1$ and from here $x = 0$ or $x = -1$, but they are both non acceptable.

Thence it must be $\mu > 0$ hence the second constraint is active. From here I got $y = -x$, so that the first equation becomes $x^2-x-2 = 0$, hence $x = 2$ or $x = -1$ but the second is again not acceptable.

With $x = 2$ I ave $y = -2$ hence the point I get is $(2, -2)$ which is fine, with $\lambda = 1$ and $\mu = 2$.

**QUESTION**

How do I go on from here? How I understand if this is a max or a min? Since my feasible region is not compact, I cannot state it's a maximum.

**Also** I cannot use geometric methods like level curves.

Can you help me? Is there some general approach?

Comment: Why are you introducing a Lagrange multiplier for an inequality constraint? Are you considering the equality constraint $x+y=0$? There is a bordered Hessian test for Lagrange multipliers, but it’s probably easier just to analyze $f$ near your constrained critical point.

Comment: Note that with your constraints, it must be the case that $x\in [0, 2]$.

Comment: @TedShifrin I introduced the Lagrangian because I can. Lagrangian + Kuhn Tucker conditions, there is nothing wrong in this method.

Comment: @CheeHan $x = 2$ hence $x \in [0, 2]$. I don't get...

Comment: @TedShifrin So like $f(2 \pm \epsilon, -2 \pm \epsilon)$ and see what happens...?

Comment: I don't think using the lagrangian with an inequality constraint is helpful, instead i would use as lagrangian the function $L(x, y, \lambda) = 2x - y - \lambda(x^2+y-2)$, find the critical point of this function and then check if they satisfy $x\geq 0, x+y\geq 0.$

Comment: Substituting $y = 2 - x^2$, your objective function becomes $f(x) = 2x - (2 - x^2)$ and you are maximising over the closed interval $[0, 2]$.

Answer (score 0):

The feasible region **is** compact. It's the portion of the parabola $y = 2 - x^2$ for $0 \leq x \leq 2$. The parallel lines are some of the level curves of the objective function, which you can see takes its maximum on this curve at $(x, y) = (2, -2)$, where $f(x, y) = 6$.

[image: Optimization of linear objective over compact parabolic constraint.]

When you have a finite collection of candidates for max and min, just evaluate the objective function at those points (in a table if you like) and pick out the largest and smallest.

Comment: Oh, thank you so much!! I really missed the compactness. I am tired. My I ask you: what if the region is NOT compact and I obtain only one point, how should I proceed?

Comment: It's more subtle. There's no guarantee that an arbitrary function $f:D \to \mathbb{R}$ has a max or min. The [Extreme Value Theorem](https://www.wikiwand.com/en/Extreme_value_theorem#Generalization_to_metric_and_topological_spaces) guarantees that the function achieves its max and min when $D$ is compact and $f$ is continuous over $D$. Outside of these hypotheses, we have to be more careful.